# How to check if an iOS device is a retina display iPod touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch

Is there a safe way to determine that a device is of a particular model? For example I must know if the device the user uses is a retina display iPod touch.

Comment: What is the reason you need to know that? It is better to check for individual device capabilities rather than a specific model.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1323251

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSRange r = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] rangeOfString:@"iPod"];
float s = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

if (r.location != NSNotFound && s > 1.5f) {
    // retina iTouch
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably try something like this:

```
+(BOOL) isRetinaiPod
{
    return [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"] && [UIScreen mainScreen].scale >= 2.0f;
}
```

However you can return the device's name with this:

```
+ (NSString *) deviceName 
{
    struct utsname u;
    uname(&u);
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:u.sysname];
}
```

Comment: `struct utsname u; uname(&u); return u;` this is wrong: struct utsname is not an NSString.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. So it is. My code was working without that, but I'm quite unsure why!

Comment: maybe you didn't ever call that method - if you had called it, it would have crashed with a segfaul. :)

Comment: I was actually returning `@(u.machine)`. Copy error. I had amended from what I actually use (I cache the value)

Comment: Ah so that's fine :) Yes, copy errors are *annoying*, happened to me also.